# Facebook SSO not returning to my app iphone

Tags: ios, iphone, facebook, single-sign-on

I published app on the AppStore. Before sending Apple, app worked fine. I downloaded this app, and when I run the Facebook login screen appears Dialogue permission.
When I click "ok", app does not return but is on Facebook.
I followed the letter of the Facebook documentation.

Any help/suggestions would be very much appreciated.

Thanks

Jean-Louis

Comment: Without any code, Do you think anyone can help you? Actually facebook API would be updated by facebook site. So your code may be become outdated .So it will not work anymore.

Comment: show us your code so we can help you.

Comment: I am having the same problem, except I'm not even getting the dialog any more.  I'm looking into the possibility that I may have denied permission (for testing) and that perhaps permanently skips past the log-in/approve dialog, to the home news feed page.

Answer (score 0):

From my experience this can happen if :

- You have not set the 'url scheme' for facebook
   or
- You have not implemented

  - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application handleOpenURL:(NSURL *)url

properly

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had a space between the fb and my fb app id... silly but that was the problem.